# how put iptv rtmp in jwplayer

Tags: rtmp, live-streaming, jwplayer6

I want to put spanish public tv in my web if that is possible.

I found this web (http://iptv-free.blogspot.com.es/2014/03/simpletv-playlist-iptv-spain.html) with the rtmp directions for SimpleTV software, but I can't put this directions in JWPlayer 6.

For example, Antena 3 HD: 
`'rtmp://$OPT:rtmp-raw=rtmp://50.7.133.122/iguide playpath=cqxe0edj69b2x42 swfUrl=http : //www.iguide.to/player/secure_player_iguide_embed_token.swf live=1 pageUrl=http : //www.iguide.to/ token=#ed%h0#w18623jsda6523lDGD'`

I'm really noob in this, so I tried including only the 'rtmp-raw' in JWPlayer:

```
jwplayer("jwPlayer").setup({
   file: "rtmp://50.7.133.122/iguide",
   height: 360,
   width: 640,
   autostart : true
});
```

The response is this error: 'Error loading stream: Could not connect to the server'.

I tryied including 'playpath' to filepath string too:

```
file: "rtmp://50.7.133.122/iguide/cqxe0edj69b2x42",
```

but is the same response.

After many searchs in google I found this -> http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/35654/cant-play-rtmp-url-on-jwplayer/.

Is there any way to put this channels on my web?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do such a thing. TV networks usually check a setting on their streams to restrict the stream to their domain so trying to play the stream from a different domain won't work.